# How to include a method in xml serialization in .NET (REST) Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am currently implementing a Web API project in .NET and I use the standard RESTful paths to perform CRUD operations on my Models via a Controller. For the sake of the question, let's assume I have a "Product" model.

When I call GET .../api/product/5 for example then I am successfully able to return the specific product, rendered as XML, to the requester by simply returning the relevant Product object in the GetMessage method in the controller as per convention. Serialization of the object happens "automagically".

Now, this works fine if I am simply rendering the properties for the Product object. But now, I have a method defined in Product that does some calculations. I also want to return this value in the XML. (To the receiving end it will appear just as another field - the receiver will not know that this is a calculated field rather than a property field read from the database) How do I get the value as calculated in the method to also be included in the response XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get the value as calculated in the method to also be included in the response XML?

Instead of returning a `Product` instance from your method design a view model:

```
public class ProductViewModel : Product
{
    public string SomeCalculatedField { get; set; }
}
```

and then return this view model from the action after setting the calculated field.

As an alternative from deriving from the `Product` class you could have it as property:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public string SomeCalculatedField { get; set; }
}
```